# How can i use the command translate in linux terminal

Tags: command-line

```
DHX36   PMID:26489465;;PMID:26267306;PMID:32461552;PMID:32337838
```

and I want to remove one ";" and arrive to this:

```
DHX36   PMID:26489465;PMID:26267306;PMID:32461552;PMID:32337838
```

Can I use this by using the command translate?
I've tried this but didn't work

```
tr ";;" ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `tr` for this, you will need the `-s` (`--squeeze-repeats`) option:

```
$ echo 'DHX36 PMID:26489465;;PMID:26267306;PMID:32461552;PMID:32337838' | tr -s ';'
DHX36 PMID:26489465;PMID:26267306;PMID:32461552;PMID:32337838
```

Alternatively, with `sed`:

```
$ echo 'DHX36 PMID:26489465;;PMID:26267306;PMID:32461552;PMID:32337838' | sed 's/;;/;/g'
DHX36 PMID:26489465;PMID:26267306;PMID:32461552;PMID:32337838
```

(you can omit the `g` if there is only one `;;` per line to be replaced).